# Difference between isopropyl and isobutyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Knowing the meaning of ''iso-'' prefix, i could not understand why it is used in some cases. For instance

*n-propyl* and *isopropyl*

are named according to the carbon atom which has a lack of hydrogen. The same goes for

*isobutyl*

where branches define the common name as well. In the end my question is: What is the logic of using iso- prefix (especially in those cases), and how can i know when to use it?

p.s- if you know the answer to my question, it is mostly appreciated to state your source of answer!

Comment: ISO is used when all carbons except last form a straight chain.

Comment: It looks like verifying my question, but could you expand this a bit? For instance what do you mean exactly with 'straight chain'?. Besides, is there any exceptions for this king of application?

Comment: You might have gotten the meaning wrong, there is no lack of hydrogen. More info in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IUPAC Organic Chemistry Nomenclature does not explicitly define the "iso-" prefix meaning, as it is not used in the systematic naming. However, it is mentioned on several places when listing acceptable semi-systematic names. In the section [A-2](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm) (1979 Blue book, some also in 1993 Recommendations, section [R-9.1](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_679.htm), [table 19a](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_679.htm)) those are (not mentioning *neo*- compounds)

- isobutane (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>3</sub>
- isopentane (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>3</sub>
- isohexane (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>3</sub>

And in the section [A-2.25](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm#a_2__25) (some also in R-9.1, [table 19b](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_682.htm)), where it lists acceptable "isoalkyl group" names:

- isopropyl (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−
- isobutyl (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>2</sub>−
- isopentyl (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−
- isohexyl (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−

Some related isomeric alkyls mentioned in this section are

- *sec*-butyl CH<sub>3</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH(CH<sub>3</sub>)−
- *tert*-butyl CH<sub>3</sub>−CH(CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>−
- *tert*-pentyl CH<sub>3</sub>−CH<sub>2</sub>−CH(CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>−

There are also some other, unsaturated "isoalkyl" group names mentioned:

- isopropenyl CH<sub>2</sub>=C(CH<sub>3</sub>)−
- isopropylidene (CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>C=

From the above we can induce that "iso-" prefix, when related to alkanes or alkyl groups, it means the **simplest (n-)alkane/alkyl isomer branched at the end of the carbon chain**.

Isopropyl happens to be secondary (*sec*) alkyl (there's lack of carbon atoms to create primary alkyl isomeric to the *n*-propyl), all higher isoalkyls are primary (no branching at the alkyl "attachment").